# Return empty XML fragment

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

**Is it possible to return an empty XML fragment in PLSQL?**

I can produce a populated fragment with no problems using `XMLFOREST`

Example

```
<USERID>12345</USERID>
```

But if the database field value returned is `NULL` no tags are created?

Ideally I would like the value returned to be `<USERID />` when a `NULL` value is passed. I'm not sure if I am able to transpose the value using `NVL` or `REPLACE`?

[Click here for some example code](http://rextester.com/LOWEPQ64802).

Thanks in advance

Comment: `<USERID />` is the same as `<USERID></USERID>`

Comment: Thank you @clinomaniac . question edited

Comment: Not with [xmlforest](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/XMLFOREST.html): "If *value_expr* is null, then no element is created for that *value_expr*." Well, you *could* use nvl and then replace that dummy value in the generated string, but that's horrible. If you supply some sample data and expected results we might be able to suggest alternative approaches.

Comment: @AlexPoole I am not querying any information at the moment but I have produced an example and added it to my question. Thank you.

Comment: In your example you can use `''` and it'll give you an empty element (which is odd, as Oracle usually treats that as equivalent to null); but you can't generate that distinction from a function - so when you're using a database field  that won't help. That's partly why it would be useful to know how you're getting the data. There are various ways to generate XML from relational data.